# Passing parameters evaluation direction in macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, operator-precedence

As I know in **C**, passing of actual parameters of a function evaluation starts from rightmost and directed to left.
What is the case for a macro definition with parameter? I made a code to make the sense clear but output confused me...
Here is the code.,

```
#define parsing(a,b) a*b

int parsefun(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;    
}

int main()
{
    int i=10;
    printf("%d\n",parsing((i++),i));
    i=10;
    printf("%d\n",parsing(i,(i++)));
    i=10;

    printf("%d\n",parsefun((i++),i));
    i=10;
    printf("%d\n",parsefun(i,(i++)));
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs,
100
100
100
110

I hoped same output for macros as function. But where is the crucial point here?

Comment: 'As I know in C' -- Since you're incorrect, it's worth considering why you thought you knew that, and what else you might think you know that is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> parsing of actual parameters of a function starts from rightmost and directed to left

I think you mean "evaluation" rather than "parsing".  But that's not true, the C standard does not specify an order.

So the behaviour you're getting for the functions is **unspecified** by the C standard.

> I hoped same output for macros as function

Macro arguments are not evaluated, they're simply substituted.  So you end up with this:

```
int i=10;
printf("%d\n", (i++) * i);
i=10;
printf("%d\n", i * (i++));
```

After which, you're simply seeing **undefined behaviour**, as explained in this question: [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc).

Comment: If order is unspecified, then why the two function call above giving different result?? And what value substituting above two macro substitution?? can you please explain...

Comment: @alaminhosain: Because for this particular compiler, function arguments appear to be evaluated from right to left.  But another compiler could choose to do left to right.

Comment: if you dont mind please give me the link of C standard if you can.. I read from a book that stuff probably pointers in c by kanetker

Comment: @alaminhosain: Sure.  See e.g. section 6.5.2.2 paragraph 10 of the C99 standard.

Comment: @alaminhosain See www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf (it's essentially the same as C99, but is free)